# How can I optimize my java stream code to prevent out of memory exception

Tags: java, memory, stack, java-stream, heap-memory

I have some logic running that converts 3442 XML nodes into Strings and in the next step into `JSONObject` objects.
All this is happening in a Java Stream. As soon as the `.collect(Collectors.toList())` terminal operation is called I receive the following error:

```
Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:184)
    at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:335)
    at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:399)
    at org.json.XML.parse(XML.java:399)
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:564)
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:616)
    at org.json.XML.toJSONObject(XML.java:490)
    at com.promaterial.importer.knauf.converter.XmlElementExtractor$$Lambda$932/0x000000010081f440.apply(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1654)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at com.promaterial.importer.knauf.converter.XmlElementExtractor.extractToJSON(XmlElementExtractor.java:95)
```

I have to admit that I am unsure if this is really the source of the problem. What I tried is partialising the `nodes` objects into smaller chunks. But I end up having the same problems since I never really release heap space after a `partition` is finished.
Is there a way to release a `List<JSONObjects` after I am done with it's processing?

This is the code:

```
  public static List<JSONObject> extractToJSON(InputStream inputStream, String elementName) throws IOException, SAXException, XPathExpressionException {
    try {
      List<Node> nodes = toXMLNodeList(inputStream, elementName);
      LOG.info("Extracting {} xml nodes", nodes.size());
      return nodes.stream()
              .map(XmlElementExtractor::convertNodeToString)
              .map(XML::toJSONObject)
              .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
      LOG.error("DocumentBuilder has been misconfigured");
    }
    return new ArrayList<>();
  }
```

Comment: Although streams add a small overhead the problem is that you are loading everything into memory. Either increase the memory or use [SAX parsing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/sax/parsing.html) to get an event-based solution which should allocate less memory.

Comment: So there is no other way? I mean the file is already in memory and at that point I have OOM yet

Comment: No way to tell if you don't show full code, JVM memory settings and the size of loaded XMLs. It looks like you are using DOM parser which loads the data into memory just to get specific nodes which is potentially wasteful (hard to tell from the code snippet). If there is OOME inspect the heap dump to figure out what is taking the space.

Comment: ok I try the event based approach. you can define it as answer

Comment: Loading a file into memory is not the same thing as constructing JSON objects from the file contents – object construction will consume memory beyond file parsing. As @KarolDowbecki pointed out, using a SAX parser might get around the memory constraints.

Comment: @xetra11start by inspecting [the heap dump](https://dzone.com/articles/memory-analysis-how-to-obtain-java-heat-dump), don't tune the code blindly.